# In Plugin WP User Avatar Get Avtar URL Not With img src tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want user avatar Image URL... 
`get_wp_user_avatar();`

When i use this function its return image with image tag , i want only url

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got It:

```
 function scrapeImage($text) {
    $pattern = '/src=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)[\'" >]/';
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $link);
    $link = $link[1];
    $link = urldecode($link);
    return $link;

}
```

---

```
$avtarimg =  scrapeImage(get_wp_user_avatar($user_info->ID));
echo $avtarimg ;
```

Comment: No need to use preg_match. They have a built-in function get_wp_user_avatar_src() to get the local avatar source link.